# "Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 4.x" error BUT my current environment is 6.11

Tags: node.js, maven, npm-install, node-sass

This always happen to me when I change my node version globally and is not the same as the project version installed by Maven.

Things normally work ok but node-sass always gives error. I recently updated my node version from 4.4.4 globally to stable version with nvm.

Our project setting also changed to be 6.11.3

I deleted project node-modules many times. I cleaned npm cache many times both in global and in project local.

But Grunt watch does not work because I get this

> > Error: Missing binding /Users/Tekin/bitbucket/ark/code/emport-web/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-46/binding.node
> >     Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 4.x
> >
> > Found bindings for the following environments:
> >       - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This is driving me insane. What is happening? I am not using 4.x anymore I rebuilt npm node-sass also even forced it. 
May be there is an order of things that someone can explain.

And this is what I get when I do npm install or Jetty clean run to rebuild the project.

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /Users/Tekin/bitbucket/ark/code/emport-web/node_modules/node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js
>
> node-sass build Binary found at /Users/Tekin/bitbucket/ark/code/emport->web/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-48/binding.node
>
> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall /Users/Tekin/bitbucket/ark/code/emport-web/node_modules/node-sass node scripts/build.js
>
> Binary found at /Users/Tekin/bitbucket/ark/code/emport-web/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-48/binding.node
>   Testing binary
>   Binary is fine
>   node-sass@4.5.3 /Users/Tekin/bitbucket/ark/code/emport-web/node_modules/node-sass

Comment: From what I know, `nvm` (I assume you mean that) never installs globally. I would suggest using the official Node.js installer to install a proper global version of Node.js, and use `nvm` to install/switch between different version of Node.js if you happen to need that functionality.

Comment: Yes thanks it is nvm. I changed it. But that doesn't make sense because I have never used anything else since 0.x Node and before everything was set up for v4.4.4. if I do nvm list I have 4 versions. Also do you mean that local project node installed by maven  is not being respected either? If I switch to 4.4.4 with nvm it will work I know but that is not what we want.

Comment: I think I have resolved the issue. (Well partially.)
It was my Webstorm setting that the task runner was looking at usr/local/bin/node folder rather than the project root node folder. And there was the nvm folder path too. So when project is installing node 6.11.3 the local might be different version. Hence bindings issue occurs.
What it doesn't solve why even I change my local node to 6.11.3 and rebuild node-sass I get the error still. Because they should match. 
But at least I am running grunt watch and sass tasks now.

Comment: I don't know Maven, but are you saying that it installs a full Node.js "distribution" inside a project directory? That's weird. However, if Webstorm is looking at `/usr/local/bin/node` (which is typically the location of a globally installed Node), and you only used `nvm` to install 6.11.3, it makes sense that you're running into problems. Webstorm probably has no idea about `nvm`.

Comment: Yes on the having problems with local and nvm differences. But webstorm does look at nvm folder too. It is listed in the options. Still the configuration was looking at local/bin and I was getting error because nvm folder shows I have 6.11.3 but local/bin binding for sass I guess was 4.x. The project is using 6.11 and maven build is fine but grunt and browserifty tasks did not work because webstorm was not using right binding. So fixed by changing path to project node. We could also change it to nvm folder so when we swap nodejs with nvm, other projects would run too.